# Pseudorandom increasing sequence

Tags: cr.crypto-security, pseudorandom-generators

I am looking for a way to generate an increasing sequence of integers $(x_i)$ such that the sequence of differences $(x_{i+1}-x_i)$ is pseudorandom (in any common way of defining pseudorandomness). It should be possible to efficiently find the $k$-th element in the sequence for a given $k$.

Nonexamples:

1. A linear congruential generator is not increasing, but it is possible to generate the $k$-th element, $x_k = A^kX_0+(1+\dotsc+A^{k-1})B \pmod{p}$, using $O(log(k))$ arithmetic operations.
2. Accumulating the sum of a linear congruential generator gives a sequence with the desired pseudorandomness property, but I don't know how to get the $k$-th element efficiently.

Comment: How do you define _efficiently_? Presumably you mean less than $O(k)$.

Comment: @DaveClarke: Yes. Less than O(k). And hopefully much closer to O(log(k)).

Comment: Are you sure that the sequence $\{x_k\}$ defined by recurrence $x_{k+1}=Ax_k+B \bmod p$ is pseudorandom enough for you?  It is not pseudorandom in almost any definition because given p (which is usually fixed), the whole sequence can be predicted from the first three terms.

Comment: Please define "pseudorandom".  Do you mean "approximately uniform"?  Or do you just mean "unpredictable"?

Comment: @JɛﬀE: Unpredictable would be enough.

Comment: Did you read my previous comment?

Answer (score 3):

Given that you said it would be enough for the sequence to be unpredictable, here is a very simple solution.  The $i$th value in the sequence is given by

$$x_i = 2^{128} i + y_i$$

where $y_i$ is any pseudorandom sequence where you can efficiently find the $i$th value ($y_i$) and where each $y_i$ is 128 bits wide (i.e., $0 \le y_i < 2^{128}$).  For instance, you could use

$$y_i = F(K,i)$$

where $F$ is any pseudorandom function (e.g., AES) with a 128-bit output, and $K$ is a key (the seed from which the entire sequence is generated).